# Changed my network and wifi printer stopped working

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I recently moved around my networking devices and now my WiFi printer isn't being detected. I know why but I don't know how to fix it.

My PC is hooked directly into the Comcast modem in the basement.

From the Comcast modem, I ran an ethernet cable upstairs to a router (for better signal). The printer is connected to this wireless connection.

How do I get the computer to see the printer when it's connected to a different device? I'd prefer to not enable the Wifi on the Comcast box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your printer is wireless, the computer needs to look for it on the wireless network, not on the ethernet cable (which is not connected to the wireless network). You would need an additional wireless network card at your computer, or you have to pluck your computer's ethernet cable into the router instead of the modem, so the computer is a part of the routers network.

Right now, your computer is in its own network with the modem and the router, and the printer is on the other side of the router, in the routers network.

Comment: OK I have a cheap USB wireless card that I used to use on the computer. Can I use that to connect to the same WiFi point to use the printer?

can the PC be connected to both the ethernet and wifi? Would it prioritize the ethernet because it's faster?

Comment: OK that apparently won't work. I have the PC connected to both the WiFi and the modem. It's not detecting the printer on the router.

Edit (again). It works. The driver installation discovered the printer and it's working.

Is there any downside to being connected to both the modem and Wifi directly?